How to have newly pointed domains to IP address always pointing to one website automatically?
I am looking to find solution to hosting something like URL Shortener website that has Custom Domains feature which enables users to add their own custom domain pointed to the main site that I have so they can use the new domain for link redirection.
I have Ubuntu 22.04, Hestia CP, SSH access, PHP 8.2 and I see /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf file with only Document Root path to /var/www/html, however I have my site hosted in /home/username/web/domain.com/public_html/public/ folder.
Editing the 000-default.conf to change the Document Root didn't help.
Editing the apache.conf in /etc/apache2/ folder also didn't help.
It helps me so far only to log in to Hestia CP and add the domain manually and point it to the domain.com website, but that trigger manual process, I want something automatic like editing .conf file.
Please, is there any solution to this like making my virtual host capable of doing something like this? What files I have to edit and with what code?
